# Cant receive push notifications from Salesforce Marketing Cloud Mobile Push App

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, mobilepush

I have been trying to send push notifications to my test mobile app and I cant receive them at all. Although I can see that my device contact has been created in All Contacts..

I keep getting the below error.
[image]

My test mobile app is not in play store, it is just running on my phone. I have provisioned my app using FCM and received the Server key, Legacy Server key
 and senderid.

And I am not sure which Id to use while provisioning the app under GCM Client field in the marketing cloud app center.
Please let me know which Id to use under GCM Client?
Does the mobile app need to be in app store to test notifications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. The Legacy server key is the API key to be used under the GCM Client

Comment: You are 100% correct.